# Test saving ggplots

Tags: r, unit-testing, ggplot2, testthat

I'm creating bunch of tests for ggplots. I included things like checking labels, if the output object is ggplot etc. But I have no idea how to test if the plot was saved using `testthat` and `ggsave`. Do you have any idea how it can be done ?

Comment: `help("file.exists")`?

Comment: That's a good hint! Drawback of this solution is that I have to provide name of the file. My files are being saved regarding to date, so it's very involved to do it while testing. Do you have maybe other idea which does not include name of the file ? ;))

Comment: Testing if something was saved means testing that a specific file exists. I don't see how you can savely do this without using the file name. Maybe check the number of graphics (e.g., png) files in the directory before and after the save action? I'd consider that suboptimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to test based on file size. If the file doesn't exist it is NA and if it does exist it should be > 0.

```
library(testthat)
library(ggplot2)

test_that("plot is saved to file", {
  file <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
  expect_equal(file.size(file), NA_real_)
  
  plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
    geom_point()
  
  ggsave(file, plot, "png")
  
  expect_true(file.size(file) > 0)
  
  unlink(file)
})
```